# asp.net c# login webpage error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web, authentication

i got the following problem:

Im making a website using asp.net and c# and in the very first page is the login, the HTML is basically 2 textfields and 1 button, wich request the following function:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

         ServicioIS.Service1SoapClient objeto = new ServicioIS.Service1SoapClient();
          string a = ci.Value.ToString();
          string b = pass.Value.ToString();
          // bool x = objeto.Log(a,b);
          bool flag = false;
          SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
          con.ConnectionString = "Server=.;database=Proyecto.mdf;user=;password=";
          con.Open();
          string check = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Admin WHERE login ='" + a + "'";
          SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(check, con);
          int cont = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
          con.Close();
          if (cont == 1)
          {
              con.Open();
              string checkpass = "SELECT pass FROM Admin WHERE login = '" + a + "'";
              SqlCommand ds = new SqlCommand(checkpass, con);
              string contra = ds.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");
              con.Close();
              if (a == contra)
              {
                  flag = true;
              }
          }
           if (flag)
           {
               Response.Write("Contraseña Correcta");
           }
           else
           {
               Response.Write("usuario o contraseña invalidos");
           }


     }
```

the error and the stack trace is the following:

```
Line 31:               SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
Line 32:               con.ConnectionString = "      "Server=.;database=Proyecto.mdf;user=;password=";
Line 33:               con.Open();
Line 34:               string check = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Admin WHERE   login ='" + a + "'";
Line 35:               SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(check, con);

Source File: c:\Users\Fabrizio\Desktop\Nueva carpeta     (2)\ProyectoIS\WebAppIS\WebAppIS\Interface\Login.aspx.cs    Line: 33 

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,     Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5347119
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject  stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +546
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand   cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler,   TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1693
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +69
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +30
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +317
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +892
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +311
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +646
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +278
 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +732
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +85
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1057
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +196
 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +94
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +110
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
WebAppIS.Interface.Login.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in  c:\Users\Fabrizio\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (2)\ProyectoIS\WebAppIS\WebAppIS\Interface\Login.aspx.cs:33
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9627718
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl,   String eventArgument) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

PD: im using Visual Studio 2012 if it makes it any easier to fix it :)

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: In don't iknow how much of this is a copy paste error... `Server=.;database=Proyecto.mdf;user=;password=` you don't have a user in your connection string, and based on the stack trace, that is your issue.

Comment: also sql injection, you need to parameterize inputs

Comment: Forgot to add that the error is in the line 33 "con.Open();" 
Also i made the database with VisualStudio and i dindt asked for a user nor pw, so i tough ill just leave it blank? what should i do?

Comment: Hi @FabrizioBruzzese are you using Windows authentication ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a user authentication problem.  SQL hides the details of the error for security reasons, but you should be able to find more information in your SQL Server error log.  Refer to the following link for troubleshooting info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366351.aspx

Comment: thanks for the answer, this is new stuff for me still trying to figure it out... I think ill just use xml for now.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL error means your application does not have permissions on the database.  I believe that is because you are providing a user and password attribute but leaving them blank.  Try using a trusted connection.

```
con.ConnectionString = "Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=Proyecto.mdf;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;";
```

Also, it was noted in the comments that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  That is very true.  You should use parameterized SQL to add your variable to the SQL statement as shown below.

```
SqlParam param;

string check = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Admin WHERE login=@LoginName";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(check, con);
param = new SqlParameter("@LoginName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
param.Value = a;
com.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the code, this is new stuff for me so and is getting out of hand (i did once a database little app so i tough i could do this aswell), ill just use xml for now i guess. Im very gratefull for the info tho

Comment: You're welcome.  If you find a post helpful, it's customary to up vote it.  And also to select the most helpful post as the accepted answer.  These up votes and accepted answers help us unlock abilities on this site.